# Query all pair of points whose distance is smaller than a threshhold

Tags: c++, knn, kdtree

The problem is simple, just like the query_pair method in python scipy [kdtree implmentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

I want a c/c++ version of that. However, I find typically a kd-tree implementation only offer API of NN, k-NN, Range query.

I try to implement query_pair in c++ by using range query as the building blocks. However, in this way, I have to filter the result since each pair of point will be found twice. The performance is not good enough.

I want to know two thing:

1. is there any way specifically for efficient point pair query? even an approximate one is enough.
2. in some paper 'Reduced hair models', it said that k-NN is more efficient than fixed range search because of more efficient pruning. Why?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ kdtree example" or "c++ kdtree search".  Usually searching the internet before posting to StackOverflow is more productive (sometimes you can see similar or duplicate questions already posted to StackOverflow).

Comment: I am afraid that your comment is not fair. You definitely did not read my question in detail. I have searched much of the impl of kdtree and find none of them has the API that I request. Also, I google scholar the problem and still cannot find an proper description/formulation of that question. After all day's effort, i came here and asked.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews You have to noticed that I am not asking how to do kNN search or other common query for kdtree, but to query all pairs of point pairs close enough in an efficient way. Also, I give my naive impl of this algorithm using range neighbor search and feel that it is not efficient enough. If you think I am lazy or not talented at google, plz show your results.